# Flutter with FirebaseMessaging ^8.0.0-dev.14

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

How would I implement the FirebaseMessaging for my flutter app to send push notifications? Before one would use the configure() method but that is depreciated. I am able to receive notifications on IOS but not Android. I currently have this in one of my dart screen files:

```
final fbm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fbm.requestPermission();
  }
```

Comment: Check the new api: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage

Comment: @DarShan Do you have any examples of implementation? The docs aren't very helpful.